# Xcode view doesn't fully update over VNC

Tags: macos, vnc, ultravnc, tightvnc

I use UltraVNC to work on my Mac remotely, and I've noticed that Xcode 4.2 doesn't fully refresh over VNC.  The rectangle (shown below) that shows the current status of Xcode underneath the current project and file will only update when

- I'm in Xcode and I click on to another application; or
- I'm in another application and I click on to Xcode.

[image: The box that doesn't refresh.]

So it seems like it only does a full refresh when the focus changes.  I've tried using both UltraVNC and TightVNC, as well as TightVNC on Linux, and they all show the same behavior.  I'm using the built in OS X Screen Sharing capability.  This isn't a huge deal, as I can find other ways to get the information that is shown there, but it would be nice if I could find a way to get that to refresh consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two host programs on the mac to provide video for ultravnc clients: OS X Screen Sharing and Apple Remote Desktop. The remote desktop option has more functionality, and I'm guessing that it might have better detection of the missed video painting that xcode is using. Here's some info on [using Remote Desktop with UltrVNC.](http://cyberparticle.wordpress.com/2008/02/17/remote-control-your-mac-using-ultravnc-from-windows-vista/)
Another option to try is to change the video encoding format from the client side:
[Ultranet video encoding options](http://blog.connectwise.net/staying_connected_the_off/2009/02/remote-control-mac-osx-using-ultravnc.html)
(Although, I'm guessing that's less likely to help what appears to be the host not sending the updated video event).

Comment: I'm thinking that this is just one of those Mac things that I'll have to get used to.  I tried the info at both of those links, and wasn't able to get anywhere.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I updated my mac to Lion, and it looks like that has fixed this issue.